# Managing SVN projects for continuous integration with CruiseControl.NET

Tags: .net, svn, cruisecontrol.net

We've decided to implement CC.NET to have a readily available build for our various projects in Subversion, but the challenge we're facing is that we use some heavy references like NHibernate.dll which is quite large, and might not be very efficient to check out all the time by CC .NET.

Can anyone provide advice that could assist us in setting up the correct environment? Also, how does CC .NET handle references of other projects in SVN?

Thanks a ton

Comment: Is your concern the size of some of your DLLs? It would only be downloaded once unless you are doing a clean get each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the challenge we're facing is that we use some heavy references
>   like NHibernate.dll which is quite large, and might not be very
>   efficient to check out all the time by CC .NET.

Cruisecontrol.net is a queuing system. It also provides a toolbox for running items in the queue when it's their turn. ccnet simply executes tasks and manages things like build logs, build artifacts and sending emails about the build. So basically you'd setup ccnet to check out your SVN project and then build it.

> Can anyone provide advice that could assist us in setting up the
>   correct environment?

The environment should be similar to the environment used to build the code. ccnet comes as an easy to use installer. You will need to install [Internet Information Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) prior to installing ccnet.

> Also, how does CC .NET handle references of other projects in SVN?

You mean SVN externals? ccnet has a thing called source controls. One of the source controls in ccnet is SVN and it provides a way to check for differences in the externals of a repository or to avoid the externals when checking for differences. [SVN Source Controls in ccnet](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Subversion_%28svn%29)

Answer (score 0):

Svn doesn't handle references, msbuild will look for them in a directory configured in the project file.
Therefore you need to ensure that said references are available when building.
You could build the common assemblies in individual ccnet projects and then reference their build directories. Of course that could be interesting when trying to perform a build on your pc's.

Hope that helps